# How to simplify?

Tags: equation-solving

The original formula is:

```
Abs[(a b)/x0]/(2 Sqrt[1 + y0^2/x0^2])
```

How do you convert operations to get this result?

```
Abs[a b]/(2 Sqrt[x0^2 + y0^2])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 r1=Abs[(a b)/x0]/(2 Sqrt[1+y0^2/x0^2])
 Assuming[x0 > 0, Simplify[r1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The trick to use to find what assumption to use is this. Write your original expression and the desired one. Then use `Reduce` and and will tell you under what conditions, if any, they are the same. This way you know what assumptions are needed. Like this

```
 r1=Abs[(a b)/x0]/(2 Sqrt[1+y0^2/x0^2]);
 r2=Abs[a b]/(2 Sqrt[x0^2+y0^2]);
 Reduce[r1==r2,Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So any one of the above assumptions will do it.

Comment: x0 is a real number

Comment: @csn899 Yes, The assumption `x0>0` implies it is real number. You can't use `>` on complex numbers.

Comment: @csn899 - [`Equations and Inequalities over Domains`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ManipulatingEquationsAndInequalities.html#18990): "But if your input involves inequalities, then Reduce will assume that any algebraic variables appearing in them are real, since inequalities can only compare real quantities."